# Gettting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYnJ22go' (Errcode: 28) in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

I am getting the 'Gettting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYnJ22go' (Errcode: 28) in magento' when open a particular page in magento-1.9 
I give write permission to my tmp folder,but no use. Still any thing I need do change to solve this. 
Please advise me .I am new to magento. Thanks.

Comment: A shot in the dark: Is your disk full?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know exactly, how to check that.

Comment: on the command line, `df -h`

Comment: Thank You. I think it will solve my problem. I will check.

Answer (score -1):

Reading about error code 28, that may be not enough space left on disc.

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,639001,639001